# Select substring based on a string of options

Tags: javascript, select, substring, matching

I have the following code

```
// this text box can contain a URL such as:
// http://vimeo.com/
// http://www.youtube.com/
// and so on.
var text = $('#myTextBox').val();
var providers = "youtube|flickr|viddler|qik|revision3|hulu|vimeo";

if( text.match(providers).length > -1) {  
  var selectedProvider = ???;
}
```

the match method looks if there are any sub-string that match the list of providers: youtube, flickr, vimeo etc.

My question is which provider was matched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the `match` result and get the first element matched:

```
var text = $('#myTextBox').val();
var match = text.match("youtube|flickr|viddler|qik|revision3|hulu|vimeo");

if (match) {
  var selectedProvider = match[0];
}
```

[`String.prototype.match`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.5.4.10) expects a `RegExp` object as argument, but if you pass a `String`, it will be replaced with the result of the expression `new RegExp(string)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. such a simple answer :)